Difference Approaches in Gravitational Wave
I have a question regarding the fundamental assumption of gravitational waves presented in Section 1.4.2 of Maggiore's Gravitational Waves, where he states:

At this point, we can understand why the linearized approximation of Section 1.1 cannot be extended beyond linear order. If we force the background metric to be $\eta_{\mu\nu}$, we are effectively setting $1/L_B$ strictly to zero. Thus, any finite, albeit arbitrarily small, value of $h$ inevitably violates the condition $h \ll \lambda/L_B$, rendering the expansion in powers of $h$ invalid. Consequently, the linearized expansion of the classical theory cannot serve as a systematic expansion. If we aim to compute higher-order corrections, we cannot assume a flat background metric.

Given that the gravitational perturbation field $h(x)$ contributes to the curvature of the background, it seems inappropriate to treat the background metric as flat. Yet, at the beginning of Chapter 2, he suggests that if we interpret the perturbation as a field on a flat spacetime, we can write $g_{\mu\nu} = \eta_{\mu\nu} + h_{\mu\nu}$. In this perspective, the concept of curvature is essentially absent, as we are now considering a flat spacetime and interpreting $h$ as a field with nonlinear self-interactions.
My question is: how can this latter approach be reconciled when general relativity is reduced to an effective field theory (EFT) for gravitational waves in “top-down” approach? Can we truly disregard the notion of curvature, despite starting from general relativity?

The point of the perturbation is that you can deal with very small curvatures in a linear way. Saying $g=\eta+h$ for some $h\ll 1$ drops many higher-order effects on the Einstein field equations which makes solving them much, much easier.

Given that the gravitational perturbation field $h(x)$
contributes to the curvature of the background, it seems inappropriate to treat the background metric as flat...

You can, theoretically, use whatever background spacetime you want, but using a complex one (like one that isn't $\eta$) just makes the math harder. The perturbation $h$ must be very small anyway, usually taken to be small enough that $h^2$ and such are negligible. That doesn't mean the background isn't flat, but it does mean that the background and the perturbation together are very nearly the background.

In this perspective, the concept of curvature is essentially absent, as we are now considering a flat spacetime and interpreting $h$
as a field with nonlinear self-interactions.

You can still have curvature, depending on $h$. It won't be much curvature, by definition, but there can be curvature. Take for example the Newtonian limit, where you do exactly this perturbation to produce a simple inverse-square gravity for a massive body: that gravity is still derived from the curvature of spacetime, it's just very weak (compared to that of black holes) and can thus be attributed to a perturbation instead of a metric of its own.
So: You don't need to disregard curvature. The point of linearization - a powerful tool, I might add - is just to intentionally specify that there is so little curvature that higher order terms drop out so that you can do easier math.
